# Fail to address multiple TLS versions due to session caching

Tags: ssl, wso2, session-timeout, tls1.2

I am using WSO2 API Manager (which support every TLS version) to communicate with TLSv1.1 service. This SSL handshake happens like this.

Client(APIM) Hello TLSv1.2
Server Hello TLSv1.1
handshake successful which is expected.

Then i change the backend service to TLSv1.2 and the handshake fails as below.

Client(APIM) Hello **TLSv1.1**
Handshake fails.

Here, the APIM initiates the Client Hello with TLSv1.1 based on previous knowledge that the server is using TLSv1.1 . But, since the server is now upgraded to TLSv1.2, it rejects communicating with APIM which is TLSv1.1 .

This is acceptable. Since it is unlikely that the backend service is changing its TLS version on the fly. But if i try after 30 minutes idle time, APIM initiates Client Hello with TLSv1.2 and Server Hello with TLSv1.2 therefore, succesfull handshake.

My assumption is this happens because after around 30 minutes, APIM's SSL session gets timeout. What i want to know is this **exact timeout value**.

I have tried every timeout value in the configuration files in both APIM and its tomcat.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've established that it's about 30 minutes. How precise do you really need it? It sounds more like you want to know what is the name of the timeout *property*.

Comment: Yes, i want to know the timeout value. Debugged [http-core](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-httpcore-nio) and [Synapse](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/). Still couldn't find the correct value. **wso2-httpcore-nio/modules/httpcore-nio/src/main/java/org/apache/http/nio/reactor/ssl/SSLIOSession.java** - This class do have getters and setters, but they evaluates to 60000 miliseconds when debug, which seems way less than actual.